# Encrypting data with a private key on iOS

Tags: ios, security, cryptography, rsa

I have found sample in "Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Programming Guide" about encrypting data with a public key. But how to encrypt with using private key and decrypt with using public key? I cannot find any samples about it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like it is impossible to encrypt with using private key.. SecKeyEncrypt doesn't support private key as input param and that's strange. Could someone suggest good third-party API providden that feature?

Comment: Found it! I've looked for encrypting but actually it is signing. So I will use this one: SecKeyRawSign (Generates a digital signature for a block of data)

OSStatus SecKeyRawSign (
   SecKeyRef key,
   SecPadding padding,
   const uint8_t *dataToSign,
   size_t dataToSignLen,
   uint8_t *sig,
   size_t *sigLen
);

Answer (score 5):

Why are you encrypting with the private key? When you encrypt with the private key, that is considered *signing* not encrypting, becuase it provides no confidentiality. If you want to "encrypt" with the private key, look into data signing, and that should allow you to "encrypt" (read "sign") with the private key and "decrypt" (read "verify signature") with the public key.

Comment: Yes, I meant signing with private key, but I cannot find how to do that with using SecKeyEncrypt.

Comment: Why it is impossible to sign with private key with using Cocoa API? That's really strange..

Comment: It is possible, just don't use `SecKeyEncrypt`, which is to **encrypt** (as explained in the documentation -- which also states that this function expects a public key as its parameter), but use `SecKeyRawSign`, which is to **sign** (and expects a private key as its parameter). Don't use a function to encrypt if your aim is to sign and not encrypt ;)